# PrimeFaces locale not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces Calendar component . But I want to display time and month in Turkish.I have written codes like this;

```
< p:calendar effect="slideDown" navigator="true"  locale="tr"
                        yearRange="1975" pattern="dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"/>
```

But it is displaying again in English.What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `locale="tr_TR"`?

Comment: yes I have tried but not worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Primefaces itself only provides english translations for localizable components like [calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml). If you need other translations you have to include them manually into your JSF via JavaScript.

Add the following JavaScript to your JSF view:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">  
    PrimeFaces.locales['tr'] = {
    closeText: 'kapat',
    prevText: 'geri',
    nextText: 'ileri',
    currentText: 'bugün',
    monthNames: ['Ocak','Şubat','Mart','Nisan','Mayıs','Haziran','Temmuz','Ağustos','Eylül','Ekim','Kasım','Aralık'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Oca','Şub','Mar','Nis','May','Haz', 'Tem','Ağu','Eyl','Eki','Kas','Ara'],
    dayNames: ['Pazar','Pazartesi','Salı','Çarşamba','Perşembe','Cuma','Cumartesi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Pz','Pt','Sa','Ça','Pe','Cu','Ct'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Pz','Pt','Sa','Ça','Pe','Cu','Ct'],
    weekHeader: 'Hf',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    timeOnlyTitle: 'Zaman Seçiniz',
    timeText: 'Zaman',
    hourText: 'Saat',
    minuteText: 'Dakika',
    secondText: 'Saniye',
    ampm: false,
    month: 'Ay',
    week: 'Hafta',
    day: 'Gün',
    allDayText : 'Tüm Gün'
};
</script>
```

See also:
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales
**EDIT:** 
PrimeFaces moved to github, so here is the new URL (even though the old one is still available up to now):
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a file `primefaces_i18n.js` inside your `resources/js` folder.
2. Copy and paste this [gist](https://gist.github.com/danielemaddaluno/cc549b8506198c46bf7d18c4df4e314b) inside it.
3. Then you can import it in your page like this:

   ```
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="primefaces_i18n.js" />
   ```
4. Periodically check [PrimeFacesLocales](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales) for translation updates