# Changing first day of the week in PrimeFaces calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

Hello I am using PrimeFaces `p:calendar` component, my question is that how to set **Monday** to be the first day of the week, not **Sunday** (default)?

Code for the tag `p:calendar`:

```
<p:calendar id="toDate" label="#{msg.date_to_report}"
    value="#{dailyCashierReport.toDate}" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r7j2.png)

Comment: Did you try setting the `locale` attribute?

Comment: how to modify the locale attribute and set it?

Comment: https://zenidas.wordpress.com/recipes/customize-first-day-of-primefaces-calendar/

Comment: Do you just want to change first day of the week or also want to change the language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces locale not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842196/primefaces-locale-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For changing just first day of the week, set `locale="en_US"` or `locale="en_GB"` (As Primefaces has only the English language in default) to the `p:calendar` component as:

```
<p:calendar id="toDate" label="#{msg.date_to_report}" locale="en_GB"
    value="#{dailyCashierReport.toDate}" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```

And add following JavaScript in your template / view:

```
<script>
    PrimeFaces.locales['en_GB'] = {
        firstDay : 1
    };
</script>
```

But, if you want to change the language as well, then see the following reference links for other available options.

[Customize first Day of the Week in PrimeFaces Calendar](https://zenidas.wordpress.com/recipes/customize-first-day-of-primefaces-calendar/)

[PrimeFaces Locales](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/localization)